# mobile jquery onclick

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, onclick

I am trying to fix a phone version website. 
http://taxilax.com/phone/ select a service type then hit send info. 
What happens is that it doesnt redirect to the:

```
    onclick="form.action='http://taxilax.com/wpcontent/themes/taxi_theme/src/forms/totheairport_process.php';"
```

it adds this to the url: http://taxilax.com/phone/#

Anyone has any idea why? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use inline JS when you have jQuery available?

Comment: i am not allow to modify anything there. i only need somehow to fix that problem. i saw that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only changing its action location and not posting the form. Your are using a link as well to post a form which is not the best idea either. You are putting href="#" that is why you are getting "#" on your URL as well. I would do this completely different but to help you quickly:

```
onclick="form.action='[put your URL here]';form.submit();"
```

This is not a good practice in my opinion because you should have a single event handler for the form submit not inline which keeps the code more maintainable. Also you should use the default HTML controls to post forms. If you want it to look like a link, just style a button or input type submit to take out the border and color etc.

You should also look at jQuery Mobile as its very good for mobile stuff.

Comment: If you check-out the source code you can see all the jQuery Mobile classes added to elements, but good suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

A more jQuery way to do this is to nix the inline-JavaScript and add an event handler like this:

```
$('.form-link').bind('click', function (event) {

    //this will prevent the link from doing what it would natively, so it won't append a hash onto the URL
    event.preventDefault();

    //select the form, if there is more than one form then you will need to alter this selctor, and update it's action as well as trigger a submit
    $('form').attr('action', '<URL>').trigger('submit');
});
```

Comment: This one is the right answer for jQuery, I was just trying to work in his parameters but this one is the right one Jasper.